# CUDA sorting library supporting a callback function

Tags: sorting, cuda, callback, thrust

Is there any CUDA library/code for sorting that allows me to specify a callback function, called every time two elements are moved/swapped?

Comment: You may be able to call the callback function inside the comparison function or functor you use for `thrust::sort`.

Comment: Yes I can, but I think (but I may be wrong) this would result in calling the callback function every time two elements are compared, not moved/swapped, am I wrong?

Comment: You could call the callback function every time the functor result is `true` (or `false`) but I think this also would rest on a variety of assumptions (connecting functor result with movement of data) about `thrust::sort` that I don't know to be valid.  Such assumptions might be valid, I simply don't know.

Answer (score 2):

`thrust::sort` calls `swap` through ADL just like `std::sort`. If you define a `swap` function for your user-defined data type, it will be called.